# How to deterministically invoke Windows dir command

Tags: ruby, windows-scripting

I'm writing a Ruby script to run in Windows. I have dir.exe in my PATH (via GnuWin32). I want my script to invoke the Windows cmd.exe-internal dir command so that others may use my script.

Comment: Why do you want it to use `dir`? Why not use Ruby's built-in ability to list the entries in a directory, and output that list?

Comment: I'm trying to find the free space on a drive.

Comment: I am quite sure there must be a better way than this for finding free space of a drive on a Windows machine. However, see https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/165881 for a working answer.

Comment: Yeh, I found that thread too. I will be sending this script to other people to use. I don't want them to have to install a gem to use it (asking them to install Ruby is a stretch). Sorry to be so restrictive, but it's important that it run with pure Ruby code, and preferably out of the box.

Comment: Here's what I'm presently doing.
`free_space = \`dir /-C\`.match(/(\d+) bytes free/)[1].to_i`

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe /c "set PATH='' && dir"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm new to (posting on) StackOverflow. I don't understand. This **is** the answer to my question. I figured it out myself.